# how to generate an encoding for subgraph from pairs of entities in R

Tags: r, dataframe, graph

I have a dataframe of significant gene-to-gene interactions that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(gene1=c("MAP3K1","ASXL1","JUN","RICTOR"),
                  gene2=c("GSK3B","IKZF1","NFKBIA","TSC1"),
                  z_score=c(-2.013,-2.075,-2.115,-2.098))

     "gene1"   "gene2"  "z_score"
"1"  "MAP3K1"  "GSK3B"  -2.013531276
"2"  "ASXL1"   "IKZF1"  -2.075402874
"3"  "JUN"     "NFKBIA" -2.115800857
"4"  "RICTOR"  "TSC1"   -2.098305589
```

I would like to encode these interaction as a graph in the following form:

```
t # df
v 0 MAP3K1
v 1 GSK3B
v 2 ASXL1
v 3 IKZF1
v 4 JUN
v 5 NFKBIA
v 6 RICTOR
v 7 TSC1
u 0 1 MAP3K1-GSK3B
u 2 3 ASXL1-IKZF1
u 4 5 JUN-NFKBIA
u 6 7 RICTOR-TSC1
```

I was wondering if there is any R package that can generate such kind of encoding from a set of nodes, such as gene entities.

I would highly appreciate any suggestions!

Thank you very much for your help!
Olha

Comment: This is interaction between nodes. I have corrected the output table

Comment: Are the z-scores relevant to anything? Is the output just supposed to be text? Because it looks like rows have a different number of values. Have you tried writing any code to do this yet? Where exactly are you getting stuck? This output format doesn't seem to appear familiar enough to justify it's own package.

Comment: I have used this format for subgraph mining ... you will just need to write a couple of lines of code. This may get you started; `unique_genes = unique(unlist(df[1:2])); v = setNames(seq_along(unique_genes)-1, unique_genes) ; e = cbind(sapply(df[1:2], function(x) v[x]), df$z_score)
 ; res = c(paste("v", v, names(v)), paste("e", apply(e, 1, paste, collapse=" "))) ; cat(res, sep="\n")` . Ive not bothered about trying to order the vertices to be the same as you show.

Comment: Thank you very much, @user20650!